# Display title instead of id from search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have spent hours on this single problem, I am desperate for help.

The below html displays the correct car name and the car.manufacture_id displays the correct manufacture id, except I need to display manufacture.name and can not figure out how to do that. How do I display car.manufacture.name?

**search.html.erb**

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
<%= car.manufacture_id %>
<%= link_to car.name, manufacture_path(car.manufacture_id) %>
<% end %>
```

**search_controller.rb**

```
  def search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @cars = []
      @manufactures = []
    else
      @cars = Car.search params[:q]
      @manufactures = Manufacture.search params[:q]
    end
  end
```

Comment: You'll probably need to provide more details about the relation between Car And Manufacture

Comment: It is really basic Car belongs_to :manufacture and Manufacture has_many :cars

Comment: The only thing I think of is that maybe Manufacturer is not being loaded in the search function (@cars = Car.search params[:q])

Comment: does `car.manufacture.id` give the same result as `car.manufacture_id`?

Comment: car.manufacture.id gives me an undefined method on 'id'. I also want to point out that I am far from being an expert on rails. So this could be some really simple concept that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do your car and manufacture models looks like, can you show the code for them? The schemas would help too. If your models are setup right `car.manufacture.name` should have worked.

If you do

```
<% @manufactures.each do |manufacture| %>
<%= manufacture.id %>
<%= manufacture.name %>
<% end %>
```

Does this work?

Also this might work, if the manufacturers are being found by `Manufacture.search params[:q]`

```
<%= @manufactures.find(car.manufacture_id).name %>
```

or if they are not

```
<%= Manufacture.find(car.manufacture_id).name %>
```

Comment: Using <%= Manufacture.find(car.manufacture_id).name %> worked perfectly. Thank you Clark, you are a life saver.